# Why can a constructor be called only once per instance?

Tags: java

Why are constructor calls in Java allowed only once per instance? If would be useful to set multiple instance variables in one call rather than calling several setters.

Comment: ??? A constructor creates an instance, you don't call the constructor on an instance but on the class. And you can set all members you want in a constructor ??? And have as many constructors as you want also...

Comment: You should rewrite this question.

Comment: @pgras: a constructor doesn't create an instance. It initializes the instance. Instance creation is not really handled by any user-level code.

Comment: From a very technical stand point the constructor does not create an instance (`this()` and `super()` cause multiple constructors to be called, so they can't reasonably be responsible for allocation), but calling a constructor through new does.

Comment: @pgras: "you don't call the constructor on an instance but on the class", actually, in JVM ByteCode: a typed object is created first, and then the cosntructor is called on the instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to set several variables at once just define a function:

```
public class Person {
  public Person(String firstName, String lastName, Date dateOfBirth) {
    set(firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth);
  }

  public void set(String firstName, String lastName, String dateOfBirth) {
    ...
  }
}
```

By definition an object is only constructed once, hence the constructor is only called once.

One thing worth noting: it's more common to favour immutability, so:

```
public class Person {
  private final String firstName;
  private final String lastName;
  private final Date dateOfBirth;

  public Person(String firstName, String lastName, Date dateOfBirth) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth == null ? null new Date(dateOfBirth.getTime());
  }

  public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
  public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
  public Date getDateOfBirth() { return dateOfBirth == null ? null : new Date(dateOfBirth.getTime()); }

  public Person withFirstName(String firstName) {
    return new Person(firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth);
  }

  public Person withLastName(String lastName) {
    return new Person(firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth);
  }

  public Person withDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
    return new Person(firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth);
  }
}
```

because a lot of concurrency issues simply go away when you do this. Not just concurrency issues too. `String`, `BigDecimal`, `BigInteger` and some other standard classes are immutable (immutable means once instantiated its state can never change). `Date` isn't. You see in the above code I have to constantly defensively copy the date of birth? That's because `Date` is not immutable. If you didn't a caller could do this:

```
public class Person {
  private final Date dateOfBirth;

  ...

  public Date getDateOfBirth() { return dateOfBirth; }
}

Person person = new Person(...);
Date date1 = person.getDateOfBirth();
date1.setTime(1000000000L);
System.out.println(person.getDateOfBirth());
```

The date of birth will have changed. That problem is caused solely by `Date` being mutable. That's another reason to favour immutability.

Comment: While I applaud the idea, I think the immutability pattern is a lot clearer if you rename the "setters" to withLastName, withDateOfBirth etc. That makes it more obvious that you're not *actually* setting it on the existing instance.

Comment: In your first example, you should make set(...) final so you can't possibly call a subclass's method in the constructor.

Comment: @ILMTitan: not necessary. calling an instance method from a constructor will never call that method overriden in a subclass as that subclass doesn't exist yet. Try it. It's often something people complain about.

Comment: @cletus To be clear, we are talking about Java.
Calling new Child() in this code, http://pastebin.com/m218acf72, will print "null is not nothing!", rather than "Parent" as you would suggest or "Not nothing! is not nothing!" as one would expect.

Comment: FWIW, I downvoted you because I don't like this approach, and I don't think you really answered the question appropriately. (I prefer duffy's answer). I don't care to go into details, merely providing an explanation of the downvote. Retaliate at will.

Comment: @silky: thanks for the comment (retaliate? seriously?). Frankly I'm just happy to know why. duffymo is basically advocating immutable objects like I am. Whats different about mine you don't like?

Comment: cletus: Mainly the 'with' bunch of methods, and that I didn't think immutability was particularly relevant here (duffy isn't advocating that, as I see, he's just saying that it should be constructed in a valid state). All things considered, probably the downvote was a little eager.

Answer (score 6):

Your mistake is assuming that you should be writing default constructors and setting all the values using setters.  An object should be 100% ready to go when it's created, so you should be writing one constructor that initializes its entire state.

It's not the Java "gods" that are mistaken, it's you.

Comment: Indeed, I think this is something that too many programmers don't understand, especially in the .NET world.

Answer (score 3):

There a deeper point here: Each method can run any number of times, zero to many, per object. The fact that a  constructor can run only once is an advantage as it allows you to write code that will be executed exactly once per object. For instance: registration, acquisition of external resources (files, sockets, DB connections), data manipulation (if you want your input to be sorted you make the sorting inside the constructor and the language ensures that sorting will take place).

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to the constructor and other constructor patterns described here is the Builder pattern. There are plenty of pages describing how it works, but can be summeraised with the following concise example:

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

```
public class Badger {
private int legs;
private boolean nose;
private List<Color> colors;

private Badger() {
    colors = new LinkedList<Color>();
}

public static class BadgerBuilder {
    private Badger badger;

    private BadgerBuilder(){}

    public static BadgerBuilder buildBadger() {
        BadgerBuilder b = new BadgerBuilder();
        b.badger = new Badger();
        return b;
    }

    public BadgerBuilder legs(int legs) {
        badger.legs = legs;
        return this;
    }

    public BadgerBuilder hasNose(boolean nose) {
        badger.nose = nose;
        return this;
    }

    public BadgerBuilder addColor(Color c) {
        badger.colors.add(c);
        return this;
    }

    public Badger build() {
        return badger;
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Badger b = BadgerBuilder.buildBadger()
                                .legs(4)
                                .hasNose(true)
                                .addColor(Color.black)
                                .addColor(Color.white)
                                .build();
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to have "BadgerBuilder.buildBadger()" instead of "new BadgerBuilder().legs(4)."...?

Comment: No particular reason, you might not want to share the constructor of the builder or maybe you want to use the Singleton pattern and do some one off initialisation on the builder.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents you from writing another method that sets all the desired fields at once. It can even be called from the constructor in order to prevent code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can call one constructor from another.

For example:

```
class MyClass {

  public MyClass() {
     // initialize what you want
  }

  public MyClass(String custom) {
    this();
    // custom initialization
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As many have mentioned, the constructor doesn't actually construct but sets the initial values on the object.  This is important in that it is the only place to set final fields that are otherwise uninitialized. This should be a clue that the constructor isn't the same as any other function. Also, having a good and complete constructor can help define the invariants.

However, there are some tradeoffs and potential pitfalls here.  It is not always correct that objects are "completely finished" when the constructor is complete.  The constructors are invoked bottom up inheritance-wise but completed top down.  Thus even when your constructor is finished, subclasses may still have work to do.  So if you pass out a reference to yourself (an escape) during construction and that other class expect the caller to be in a complete/stable state, then problems could occur because the subclasses have not had their opportunity complete.  This is particularly risky in highly concurrent code.  In this case it becomes safer or even mandatory to use a construct/init pattern.  Thus it may not be possible to get the object into a safe enough state to pass to other objects in the constructor.  The are many cases where objects have circular dependencies and it becomes necessary to do basic construction on all then init them all.

IRC Josh Bloch (Effective Java) and Brian Goetz (Java Concurrency in Practice) both have some good discussions of these topics.  Factory construction with private constructors if often a good alternative and has many benefits and is covered by Bloch.